# Maven push only jsp without recompiling

Tags: java, jsp, maven, tomcat, web-applications

This is my first time using maven on a project. Basically, I am working in the src on a webapp and when I am ready to push a change to the target i do a mvn clean install (this was what I was told to do).

The issue is that if I am just making a minor html tweak in a jsp and want to see the results I have to wait for tests, compile copy the war over deploy, server restart and then I have to log in again.

There's got to be a better way to do this. It's making my development speed slow to a crawl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maven tomcat plugin to run an in-memory tomcat over your maven project. Any jsp or static resource changes will apply immediately. Java code changes still require you to manually stop and start the server.

To do so use following maven goal

```
mvn clean tomcat:run
```

Answer (score 0):

One other choice is jetty plugin. add jetty plugin to pom.xml,and run,that's ok.

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>8.1.11.v20130520</version>
<configuration>
<scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
<contextPath>/</contextPath>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

run your application:
    mvn jetty:run